# Flutter - appbar bottom property not updating properly with setState

Tags: flutter

I'm building an app with an appbar that has the bottom property that will only be visible if the user selects the middle item of the 3 items (item index = 1) in the bottom navigation bar. here's the code below.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int index = 2;
  TabBar bottomBar = null;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 0,
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title), bottom: bottomBar),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: index,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.teal,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bolt),
                label: ('Devices'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.pie_chart),
                label: ('Cluster'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                label: ('Settings'),
              ),
            ],
            onTap: (int index) => setState(() => this.index = index),
          ),
          body: buildPages(),
        ),
      );

  Widget buildPages() {
    // bottomNavBarPageBuilder
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        setState(() {
          this.bottomBar = null;
          print(index);
        });
        return DeviceListPage();
      case 1:
        setState(() {
          print(index);
          this.bottomBar = TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.power),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.power),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.power),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
        return TabBarView(
            children: [UserLocalPage(), Container(), Container()]);
      case 2:
        setState(() {
          print(index);
          this.bottomBar = null;
        });
        return SettingsPage();
      default:
        setState(() {
          print(index);
          this.bottomBar = null;
        });
        return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

the problem is that sometimes the setState doesn't update the "bottom" property of the appBar. here's a [video](https://puu.sh/HVj3P/e280160784.mp4) demonstrating the problem

how can I make the bottom property of the appBar be updated properly? any help would be much appreciated thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for a late answer. Would you kindly try this code for me?

Also, although I didn't change that in the code below, I noticed that your index == 2, but initialIndex == 0. I would recommend creating a const variable to represent initialIndex, like this:

```dart
  static const int initialIndex = 0;
  int index = initialIndex;
  //skipped code
  initialIndex: initialIndex,
```

```dart
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int index = 2;
  TabBar bottomBar = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DefaultTabController(
    initialIndex: 0,
    length: 3,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title), bottom: bottomBar),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: index,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.teal,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.bolt),
            label: ('Devices'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.pie_chart),
            label: ('Cluster'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: ('Settings'),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: _onTap,
      ),
      body: buildPages(),
    ),
  );

  void _onTap(int index) {
    if(index != this.index) {
      setState(() {
        this.index = index;
        switch(index) {
          case 1:
            bottomBar = TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.power),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.power),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.power),
                )
              ],
            );
            break;
          default:
            bottomBar = null;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  Widget buildPages() {
    // bottomNavBarPageBuilder
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return DeviceListPage();
      case 1:
        return TabBarView(
            children: [UserLocalPage(), Container(), Container()]);
      case 2:
        return SettingsPage();
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, now it works like a charm!! 

I'm sorry for my variable name confusion, I wanted to make it clear the 'initialIndex' and the 'index' variable are different , the 'index' refers to the initial index for the BottomNavigationBar's currentIndex. It was my intention to have the initial index value to be equal to 2 for the bottom navigation bar so that it will open the settings page at startup.